# how to android timertask in button click event

Tags: android, timertask

I am doing a project. I have got a one button and this button click event ı get data soap services.

I have a question. I do timer and this timer 3 minüte click button.. how do it?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnrefres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

**//I've done operations**
}

}




TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
**//I do btnrefres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());  // not run :(**
}
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
```

I use to but null point eror, how do it?

```
  public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {




      Button  btn_goster = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        btn_goster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          "Buton click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            });


    }
    public  void butonclick () 
    { 
        runOnUiThread ( new  Runnable ()  { 
            public  void run () 
            { 
                  TimerTask timerTask =  new  TimerTask ()  { 
                    @Override 
                    public  void run ()  { 
                    btn_goster . performClick (); 
                    } 
                    }; 
                    Timer timer =  new  Timer (); 
                    timer . schedule ( timerTask ,  40000 ,  60000 ); 
            } 
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please make the question more clear.... Add more details about your concern...

Comment: I do my soap services. button click event fonction get coordinate data... I want this button 3 minute auto click and get data my services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either performClick() or callOnClick()

```
performClick()
```

> Added in API level 1.
>   Call this view's OnClickListener
>   if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with
>   clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

```
callOnClick()
```

> Added in API level 15.
>   Directly call any attached
>   OnClickListener. Unlike performClick, this only calls the listener,
>   and does not do any associated clicking actions like reporting an
>   accessibility event.

```
imerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
btnrefres.performClick();
}
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
```

Second option is:
Add all your soap services in a function. Later call the function in setonclicklistener and in the timertask run().

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnrefres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
soapservice();
}
}

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
soapservice();
}
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);


soapservice(){
**//I've done operations**
}
```

Comment: brother ,I have a question up.